# System API to get process used memory status

Tags: c, linux, system

I have a requirement where my running application(On LINUX) will check his used memory status. On the basis of the used status it will do some clean up job. Anyone know any system API to call from C application to know the used memory status on .

Answer (score 1):

Both `free(1)` and `vmstat(8)` actually open and parse `/proc/meminfo` so you could try that.

Comment: Do these have a C API or are you suggesting use of system()?

Comment: @Swiss I am suggesting the op should `open(2)` that file or use `stdio`. Personally I would read it using `fgets` and parse that.

Comment: I see, I thought you were suggesting use of free or vmstat rather than direct use of /proc/meminfo.

Comment: @Swiss `system` has it's time and place but I think it would be misused in this case.